# Recommended Format for an HTML-embedded app?

Tags: java, c#, vb.net, applet

I am trying to develop an application that can be embedded in the HTML code of a website. I looked into using a Java Applet, but I am turned off of this option from the fact that Applets are decreasing in popularity, and that I am not totally comfortable with Java.

I have experience with Visual Studio C# and VB, and I was wondering if there was some sort of option where I could write an embed-able application using Visual Studio, and if they have some sort of equivalent or similar tool to Applets that I could utilize.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: soooo what browser are you targeting?  Arent all the venders doing away with applets/ActiveX/plugins?  Is this app not able to be transferred to an MVC/HTML/JS solution?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you want the C# code to run on the client or server side.

Server side you will have to use ASP.NET.
If you want to run on the client side (which it sounds like), this is essentially impossible due to security concerns and technological limitations (a .net clr would need to be invoked and the code passed to it for execution).

You could potentially look into using javascript based activex/com objects to invoke the clr.

Embedding C# code *was* possible in earlier versions of Internet Explorer, but no longer.